# ElasticSearch Schema Migrations

Tags: java, elasticsearch, migration

When we write an application, we also write migrations for database schema and data, we use [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) for that.

For example I am deploying an application locally as developer on my machine, application uses elasticsearch, but before adding some data I need to execute some query/mappings.

So, I want to add that query/mappings to some files, so, when another developer will deploy application on his machine, that query will be executed automatically.

What tools/library are using for migrations ElasticSearch schema?

Comment: Came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31880978/1968909

Answer (score 0):

I created a long time ago a project I'm still maintaining which creates an index with all settings and mappings if it does not exist at startup.

`elasticsearch-beyonder` is available at https://github.com/dadoonet/elasticsearch-beyonder.

For now, it works only with a TransportClient but I'm planning to add support for the Java REST Client as well.

Comment: Thanks. I am more interested about schema.