# Jhipster Elastic-search data migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, jhipster, liquibase

We are using jhipster generator for our new project. to store data it we select Postgres as well as elasticsearch, all search operation will perform using elasticsearch.

when we start the application, It use liquibase to upload csv files and dump data into tables.we added number of csv file and made some change on liquibase configuration files as well, but the problem we found right now that it is only dumping csv data into Postgres only, we are not able to find data dump into elasticsearch.

I do some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977688/liquibase-or-flyway-database-migration-alternative-for-elasticsearch). 
but still, I am struggling with implementation, any advice will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The JHipster Elasticsearch is indexing on every change over the REST resource. See [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/web/rest/BankAccountResource.java#L64). This means that all your data which you are inserting over liquibase is not getting indexed. You can use the [generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer) to reindex data which is already in the db.

Comment: Thank  you, Let me try it, I will update you on this shortly